# Python Object Detection

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, detection, shapes

I am Fairly new To python & Image Processing. Need Some Help Regarding object detection.

Things I want to achieve .

how much circle/coin is completed e.g(like in percentage)

OR

Dimensions of visible part of circle/coin e.g(length ,width)

I'am Talking about its dimensions in Frame

Currently I'am Using HoughCircle Which also gives false Detection in Picture. Give Correct detection whens only coin is present(zoomed) & it forms complete circle even when its not completely visible i.e also including hidden path.

there would be the same coin every time & it would be forming "D" type shape

Any help would be really appreciated !!!

Comment: Start by uploading an example and your current approach here.